# Start/Stop kafka listener along with assigning/revoking partition

Tags: apache-kafka

I am looking for a way to

1. dynamically start kafka listener and assign a partiton for specified topic
2. dynamically stop kafka listener and revoke the assigned partiton for specified topic

Tried googling. I do see some resources about starting/stoping listeners, but I don't see those mentioning anything about assign/revoke of partition.